# Why isn't dispatchgroup.notify executed?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I'm making multiple API calls in my app. I've created functions to wrap around and execute each of these api calls "i.e. gemini, coinbase, bitfinex etc" These functions populate an array, and therefore I need to wait for all the functions to execute before I can calculate the average of the data stored in the array. I thought the best way to do this would be to use a dispatch group. However, dispatchGroup.notify never seems to execute, and thus I'm never able to calculate the average. I'm not sure why the completion block in dispatchGroup.notify isn't executing because from what I read, all you need is to have equally matching enter() and leave() calls, which I have.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    exchangesTableView.dataSource = self

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    coinbase {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    gemini {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    bitfinex {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    kraken {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    okcoin {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    cexio {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    hitbtc {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    livecoin {
        self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
        print("inside the average function")
        var total: Double = 0.0
        var average: Double

        for eth in self.exchangesArray{

            let ethPrice: Double = Double(eth.price)!
            total = total + ethPrice

        }

        let count: Double = Double(self.exchangesArray.count)

        average = total/count
        print("The average is: \(average)")
    })
```

Here are my API wrappers:

```
func coinbase(completion: @escaping () -> Void){

    print("Inside the coinbase function")
    let url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/spot"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.setValue("2017-05-19", forHTTPHeaderField: "CB-VERSION")
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for coinbase")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                if let data = fetchedData["data"] as AnyObject? {
                    let price = data["amount"] as! String
                    self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "Coinbase", price: price))
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()

                }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error 2")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}




func gemini(completion: @escaping () -> Void ){
    print("Inside gemini function")
    let url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1/pubticker/ethusd"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for gemini")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                let price = fetchedData["last"] as! String
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "Gemini", price: price))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }

            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print("Gemini function completed...exiting")
}



func bitfinex(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("inside the bitfinex function")
    let url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/ticker/tETHUSD"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil) {
            print("Error")
        }
        else {
            do {
                print("inside the task for bitfinex")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
                let priceInt = fetchedData[6]
                let price = String(describing: priceInt)
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "Bitfinex", price: price))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.exchangesTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print("bitfinex function completed...exiting")
}



func kraken(completion: @escaping ()-> Void ){

    print("inside the kraken function")
    let url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHUSD"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for kraken")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                let data = fetchedData["result"] as AnyObject
                let xethzusd = data["XETHZUSD"] as AnyObject
                let c = xethzusd["c"] as! NSArray
                let price = c[0]
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "Kraken", price: price as! String))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }

            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}



func okcoin(completion: @escaping () -> Void ){

    print("inside the okcoin function")
    let url = "https://www.okcoin.com/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=eth_usd"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for okcoin")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                let ticker = fetchedData["ticker"] as AnyObject
                let price = ticker["last"] as! String
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "OKCoin", price: price))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }

            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


func cexio(completion: @escaping () -> Void ){

    print("inside the cexio function")
    let url = "https://cex.io/api/last_price/ETH/USD"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for cexio")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                let price = fetchedData["lprice"] as! String
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "CEX.IO", price: price))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}




func hitbtc(completion: @escaping () -> Void ){
    print("inside the hitbtc function")
    let url = "https://api.hitbtc.com/api/1/public/ETHUSD/ticker"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for hitbtc")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                let price = fetchedData["last"] as! String
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "HitBTC", price: price))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}



func livecoin(completion: @escaping () -> Void ){
    print("inside the livecoin function")
    let url = "https://api.livecoin.net/exchange/ticker?currencyPair=ETH/USD"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if(error != nil){
            print("Error")
        }
        else{
            do{
                print("inside the task for livecoin")
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                let priceInt = fetchedData["last"]
                let price = String(describing: priceInt)
                self.exchangesArray.append(ExchangeObject(name: "Livecoin", price: price))
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion()
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: As far as I tested your code with simulated API calls (simple delay using `asyncAfter`), the `execute` closure of `DispatchGroup.notify` is executed as expected. So, your API wrappers have something wrong. Please show them.

Comment: I just added the API wrappers. And I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge on my part, but as far as calling DispatchGroup notify on the main queue, how will this block the main queue if it will only execute when the rest of the API calls return?

Comment: Thanks for adding the API wrappers. You'd better move all `self.exchangesArray.append(...)` into `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` (remember, Swift Arrays are not thread-safe), but that's another issue. Maybe the most important issue in your code is that **you are not invoking `completion` in `bitfinex`**. And ignore that main-thread thing about `DispatchGroup.notify`. You can call it in the main thread, as you described.